# Unable to create group (name already exists)

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, tf.keras, h5py, attention-model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from ..models.encoder import encoder_build
from ..models.decoder import decoder_build

def compute_attention_maps(inputs,name,upsample=False):

    attMap = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(inputs),axis=-1,keepdims=True,name= str(name)+"reducSum") 
    if upsample:
        attMap = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), 
                                              interpolation='bilinear',
                                              name = str(name)+"bilinear")(attMap)
    attMap = tf.squeeze(attMap,axis=-1,name = str(name)+"squeeze")
    attMap = tf.reshape(attMap,
                        (tf.shape(attMap)[0],tf.shape(attMap)[1]*tf.shape(attMap)[2]),
                        name = str(name)+"reshape")
    attMap = tf.nn.softmax(attMap, 
                           axis=-1,
                           name = str(name)+"spatialSoftmax")
    return attMap

def compute_mse(x,y,name):

    diff = tf.math.squared_difference(x,y,name = str(name)+"squError")
    diff = tf.reduce_mean(diff,axis=0, name = str(name)+"mean")
    diff = tf.reduce_sum(diff, name = str(name)+"sum")
    return diff

def compute_distillation(attention_inputs):
    inp1,inp2,inp3,inp4 = attention_inputs 

    attMap1          = compute_attention_maps(inp1,"attmap1_")
    attMap2_upsample = compute_attention_maps(inp2,"attmap2UP_",upsample=True)
    attMap2          = compute_attention_maps(inp2,"attmap2_")
    attMap3_upsample = compute_attention_maps(inp3,"attmap3UP_",upsample=True)
    attMap3          = compute_attention_maps(inp3,"attmap3_")
    attMap4          = compute_attention_maps(inp4,"attmap4_")

    distillation1 = compute_mse(attMap1,attMap2_upsample,"distil1_")
    distillation2 = compute_mse(attMap2,attMap3_upsample,"distil2_")
    distillation3 = compute_mse(attMap3,attMap4,"distil3_")
    return tf.math.add_n([distillation1,distillation2,distillation3], name="distill_loss")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name='image')
    encoderTuple = encoder_build(inputs) # import from encoder.py file
    attention_inputs = encoderTuple[1]
    outputs = decoder_build(encoderTuple) # import from decoder.py file
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.add_loss(compute_distillation(attention_inputs))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001, clipnorm=0.001), 
                     loss='binary_crossentropy',
                     metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x = train_generator,
          epochs=epochs, 
          verbose=1, 
          callbacks=callbacks,
          validation_data=validation_generator, 
          shuffle=True)
```

i have created keras segmentation model for lane detection (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.00821.pdf). I'm able to compile, start training and save models for each epoch without any errors. But if i add my custom loss to model  **model.add_loss(compute_distillation(attention_inputs))** model gets trained for 1 epoch, after that model is not saving and displaying below error. How to resolve this error?

```
374/375 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.4717 - acc: 0.9781Epoch 1/50
 78/78[============================>.] - ETA: 37:38 - val_loss: 4.5855 - val_acc: 0.9758
Epoch 00001: saving model to /workspace/work/enet_sad_naiveresize/snapshot/enetNRSAD_Tusimple_L_4.4718_VL_4.5855.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/work/enet_sad_naiveresize/bin/train.py", line 82, in <module>
    shuffle=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 727, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 603, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 332, in model_iteration
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 299, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 968, in on_epoch_end
    self._save_model(epoch=epoch, logs=logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 1015, in _save_model
    self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1171, in save
    signatures)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 109, in save_model
    model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 103, in save_model_to_hdf5
    save_weights_to_hdf5_group(model_weights_group, model_layers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 619, in save_weights_to_hdf5_group
    g = f.create_group(layer.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 68, in create_group
    gid = h5g.create(self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, gcpl=gcpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5g.pyx", line 161, in h5py.h5g.create
ValueError: Unable to create group (name already exists)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you are stacking layers (and naming them wrongly) in compute_distillation function, by calling other functions such as compute_attention_maps and compute_mse.
You would have got a similar layer if you hadn't named also and the fact that the error persists even after you named them is because the h5 models expects names in a certain format as explained here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12195.
A good solution would be to use keras lambda layers in compute_distilation function to create attMap1, attMap2, etc. or define your own custom AttentionMap layer as shown below.

```
class AttentionMaps(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, upsample=False):
    super(AttentionMaps, self).__init__()
    self.upsample = upsample

  def call(self, inputs):
    attMap = tf.reduce_sum(
        tf.square(inputs),
        axis=-1,
        keepdims=True
    ) 
    if self.upsample:
        attMap = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(
            size=(2, 2), 
            interpolation='bilinear'
        )(attMap)
    attMap = tf.squeeze(attMap,axis=-1)
    attMap = tf.reshape(
        attMap,
        (tf.shape(attMap)[0],tf.shape(attMap)[1]*tf.shape(attMap)[2]))
    attMap = tf.nn.softmax(attMap, 
                            axis=-1,)
                            
    return attMap
```

This custom layer can then be added to your model as per the example below. The names ofthe layers are no longer required, so I removed them.

```
def compute_distillation(attention_inputs):

    inp1,inp2,inp3,inp4 = attention_inputs
    attention_layer_1 = AttentionMaps()
    attMap1          = attention_layer_1(inp1)
    attention_layer_2 = AttentionMaps(upsample=True)
    attMap2_upsample = attention_layer_2(inp2)
    attention_layer_3 = AttentionMaps()
    attMap2          = attention_layer_3(inp2)
    attention_layer_4 = AttentionMaps(upsample=True)
    attMap3_upsample = attention_layer_4(inp3)
    attention_layer_5 = AttentionMaps()
    attMap3          = attention_layer_5(inp3)
    attention_layer_6 = AttentionMaps(upsample=True)
    attMap4_upsample = attention_layer_6(inp4)
    
    distillation1 = compute_mse(attMap1,attMap2_upsample)
    distillation2 = compute_mse(attMap2,attMap3_upsample)
    distillation3 = compute_mse(attMap3,attMap4_upsample)
    
    return tf.math.add_n([distillation1,distillation2,distillation3], name="distill_loss")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues opened in the keras github related to this.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6005 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12195

This issue is not due to the custom loss function but due to the way the model is defined. 
You could try out the solutions provided in the above mentioned links such as saving the model weights as a tf file rather than h5 or avoid adding the same instance of activation layer at multiple places in the model. If that doesn't resolve your issue please update the question to include the models.